# java multiple writers and multiple readers locks

Tags: java, locks

I'm trying to implement a system that follows the following constraints :

- I have a shared resource, for example Atomic array
- I want to support multiple reads from the array simultaneously.
- I want to support multiple writes to the array simultaneously
- I dont want read and write operations to happen simultaneously.

I found [this][1] stackoverflow post regarding a similar goal but I think that the solution suggested there is allowing reads simultaneously to writes :

```
Class ReadAndWrite {
 private ReentrantLock readLock;
 private ReentrantLock writeLock;
 private AtomicInteger readers;
 private AtomicInteger writers;
 private File file;

 public void write() {
   if (!writeLock.isLocked()) {
    readLock.tryLock();
    writers.incrementAndGet(); // Increment the number of current writers
    // ***** Write your stuff *****
    writers.decrementAndGet(); // Decrement the number of current writers
    if (readLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
     while(writers != 0); // Wait until all writers are finished to release the lock
     readLock.unlock();
    }
   } else {
     writeLock.lock();
     write();
   }
  }

 public void read() {
   if (!readLock.isLocked()) {
    writeLock.tryLock();
    readers.incrementAndGet(); 
    // ***** read your stuff *****
    readers.decrementAndGet(); // Decrement the number of current read
    if (writeLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
     while(readers != 0); // Wait until all writers are finished to release the lock
     writeLock.unlock();
    }
   } else {
     readLock.lock();
     read();
   }
  }
```

As I see it, this code allows reads and writes simultaneously, for example : two threads will try to read/writer at the same time. Each one of them will enter the first if in the write/read. How can I make sure that the writes blocks the reads and reads blocks writes  ?
[1]: [Multiple readers and multiple writers(i mean multiple) synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252076/multiple-readers-and-multiple-writersi-mean-multiple-synchronization)

Comment: `#tryLock` is an optimistic locking, you need to check the return value to ensure you actually achieved the lock. If you want it to block because you couldn't lock it, _then_ you would call `#lock`. Also check out `StampedLock`

Comment: You are right, read + write can happen at the same time. I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but I think you can make a third lock `checkLocks` that is always claimed first and get released after checking and claming the other locks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking the lock repeatedly, just attempt using it:

```
private void writeInternal() {
    //thread-unsafe writing code
}

public void write() {
    if (!writeLock.tryLock()) {
        writeLock.lock();
    }
    try {
        this.writeInternal(); //in try-block to ensure unlock is called
    } finally {
        writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Using the readLock would be a similar approach. You also want to ensure you're truly using Read/Write locks and not just two separate locks:

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock;

public ReadAndWrite() {
    this.lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
}
```

Then you would access read/write locks via `this.lock.readLock()`, etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand how you make sure that reads arent happening simoultaniously to writes ? and why suddenly you decided to use ReadWriteLock ? its allows one write and not multiple writes

Comment: As you approached it previously, you would only be able to achieve 1 write at a time, or 1 read at a time, but they weren't dependent upon each other. Typically, you can have as many things reading a resource as you want at a time, but everything must wait when a writer comes along; that's a fairly typical paradigm in lock-based concurrency.